# No puedo hacer que se borren las notificaciones que el usuario ya había visto antes. Vuelven a aparecerse

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de implementar notificaciones con un `badge` al lado del icono para las notificaciones. Funciona de la siguiente manera... Cuando alguien te da un like, o comenta en tu publicación, entonces tú recibes una notificación con 5 campos... Luego el usuario que publicó dicha publicación recibe las notificaciones y también aumenta la cuenta en el badge. Luego si ese usuario abre el icono de las notificaciones que tengo en el `BottomNavigationView`, todas esas notificaciones que había recibido deberían actualizarse con un nuevo campo `"seen"`… Si la notificación en la base de datos tiene el campo seen no debería contarse... Espero que tenga sentido y que me entiendan...

El problema es que todo funciona bien, pero al salir y volver a entrar en la app si yo había mirado las notificaciones y tienen el campo seen no deberían volver a aparecer en el `BottomNavigationView` en el badge, pero siguen apareciendo allí si me salgo y luego vuelvo a entrar.

Si el usuario abre el fragmento notificaciones aparece "seen" en esa notificacion como pueden ver alli abajo. Si una notificación tiene el campo seen no tiene que contarse cuando se cuenta el numero de notificaciones "nuevas" para decirlo de alguna manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque pasa esto si tienen el campo seen, porque ya las había mirado antes...

Alguien sabe porque está pasando esto?

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                mSelectedFragment = new HomeBNVFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_search:
                mSelectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Notification notification = dataSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                            if (notification != null) {
                                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_notifications) {
                                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    hashMap.put("seen", true);
                                    reference.child(notification.getNotificationId()).updateChildren(hashMap);
                                    BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = mBinding.bottomNavigation.getBadge(R.id.nav_notifications);
                                    badgeDrawable.clearNumber();
                                    badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                mSelectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
                editor.apply();
                mSelectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                mSelectedFragment = new AttendingEventFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectedFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        return true;
    };

private void getNotifications() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Notification notification = snapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                if (notification != null) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasChild("seen")) {
                        long numberOfNotifications = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = mBinding.bottomNavigation.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.nav_notifications);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            badgeDrawable.setNumber(Math.toIntExact(numberOfNotifications));
                            badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
                            badgeDrawable.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            badgeDrawable.setBadgeTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            badgeDrawable.setMaxCharacterCount(4);
                        }
                    } else if (snapshot.hasChild("seen")) {
                        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = mBinding.bottomNavigation.getBadge(R.id.nav_notifications);
                        badgeDrawable.clearNumber();
                        badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: En dónde compruebas que el child `seen` sea true o false? Según veo el if solo comprueba que exista el child.

Comment: @Bicho no lo compruebo porque lo hago que si el child ```seen``` no existe entonces se cuenta las notificaciones porque cuando el usuario le da al icono de notificaciones en ```BNV``` se hace un ```updateChildren``` y a las nuevas notificaciones se les añade el campo seen… Me explico? Hay mejor forma de hacerlo en tu opinion? Iba a hacerlo como dices tu pero luego me di cuenta que puedo hacerlo asi, no se si es lógico...

Comment: @Bicho compurebo si el campo seen existe o no y si no se cuenta las notificaciones porque si existe es que el usuario ya habia abierto el fragmento para verlas … si no existe es que no las ha visto todavia.

Comment: Entiendo, si imprimes la estructura del `snapshot`, puedes comprobar que realice bien los if es decir si el child `seen` está presente o no, porque según entiendo no lo encuentra y por eso te muestra la notificación.

Comment: @Bicho podrias enseñarme lo que dices porque llevo trabajando en esto todo el dia y no pillo porque no me sale bien... Osea si el "seen" esta presente entonces no deberia contar esa notificacion porque el usuario ya la habia visto… Me puedes mas o menos echar una mano? Voy  a seguir intentandolo pero es que hasta ahora no me ha salido...

Comment: Puedes utilizar `System.out.println` o `Log.d`. Y de preferencia agregas el resultado del print en tu pregunta para verificar si el campo `seen` está presente.

Comment: @Bicho no me sale... No se en que estoy fallando tio. Porque me salen las notificaciones si tiene "seen". Puedes ayudarme que sigo sin poder conseguirlo ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109745/discussion-between-bicho-and-johnnnn).

Comment: @Bicho si por favor